# Override User Agent Stylesheet CSS in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, css, browser

When my webpage was rendered in the browser, it shows that one of my 'li' elements has the ":: marker" css pseudo element (I did not add this style myself) from the "user agent stylesheet". What is the "user agent stylesheet" and how do I stop this style from being applied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop user agent stylesheets from overriding my css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415385/how-to-stop-user-agent-stylesheets-from-overriding-my-css)

Comment: Thank you for this response. Specifically, the browser automatically added the following style---  "::marker {
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px !important;
    text-align: start !important;
    text-align-last: start !important;
}"

Comment: This is causing the bullet point icon to show up. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: @nCardot Do you have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ul { list-style-type: none; }` in your CSS to override the default style applied by the browser (from the user agent stylesheet) and remove the `li` bullet points

Answer (score 0):

Add `ul>li::marker { content ""; }` to your own CSS to hide the user agent stylesheet contents.

Modifying `list-style` is unlike to help, as this is extra content added outside li element.