# Background colour and text align not working

Tags: html, css

[CSS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLX7l.png)[CSS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Zhv.png)

The background colour isn't showing for the webpage https://pr0g4m3r.github.io/-user-.github.io/

I expected the background to be all black and for the words in the footer to be white, instead the background colour refuses to change and the words won't appear. The title won't center properly either.
[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Eji.png)

HTML Code:
https://github.com/PR0G4M3R/-user-.github.io/blob/main/index.html

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Shouldn't just link to a repo and no code as images. A question or answer should never rely on an external source. All relevant material should be included in the question/answer preventing link rot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your first problem is that in your styling for class body you use "background-colour" and "colour". These should be "background-color" and "color".

```css
    body {
        background-color: black;
        color: #ffffff;
        left: 5;
        float: center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>text</h1>
 </body>
```

The second part of your problem in your title is that there is user agent style sheets in chrome overriding your css.
[h1 styling getting overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEHVe.png) and
[title styling getting overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ZVK.png).

This is why your title isn't even displaying when you run your program. Please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415385/how-to-stop-user-agent-stylesheets-from-overriding-my-css) here to get this fixed. Once you get the styling to stop overriding it should work fine as you have "text-align:center;" which will center the title.

Comment: Kk, this is the website now: https://pr0g4m3r.github.io/-user-.github.io/