# Why would the rendering of my CSS styles change when using SSL?

Tags: html, css, https

I'm updating my server to access my web application via `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`. It's working, but some of my CSS styles are rendering differently.

- The CSS file **is** loading - *most* of my styles are there.
- There are **no** reports of assets failing to load in the console.
- All URLs have been updated to HTTPS.

If it's failing because there's an incorrect (HTTP instead of HTTPS) URL in the code, it's not showing up in the browser.

For instance, I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and I have a [split button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split). On the non-HTTPS site it looks right; on the HTTPS site it renders with the button on the right (with the caret symbol) about 1/2 the height it should be. I've dug into the element via the browser and it looks like the height is just not being calculated correctly for the child elements. The margins, padding, and font size are all the same.

I've stepped through the DOM using Chrome's developer console and compared the working version side-by-side with the incorrect version and I cannot find a difference.

I've opened the page in both Chrome and Firefox and find the same issue in both.

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't figure out what it is. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Another clue has surfaced: I came across [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543567/2008384) and examined the `DOCTYPE`. It turns out that the HTTP site has a doctype tag at the beginning: ` but the HTTPS site does not (which is weird, since it's in my code). So that's one important difference and I'll do some more work on figuring out where that tag is going. FWIW, I'm using Apache2 to serve the page via a reverse proxy with URL rewriting...

Comment: Possible that the style sheets are pulling in resources over HTTP that are getting blocked, using the `@import` or `@font-face`? Normally the console would report such blocks.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the console - no reports of anything blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing any protocols in URLs you have in your CSS resources to either HTTPS or leaving it blank:

```
http://somedomain.com/style.css => https://somedomain.com/style.css
```

OR

```
http://somedomain.com/style.css => //somedomain.com/style.css
```

This can be in any URLs in your HTML or CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the DOCTYPE was the issue. Apparently Apache, when functioning as a reverse proxy with `mod_proxy_html`, will strip the DOCTYPE from the page by default. I found the basic solution [here](https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4229046.htm), then checked out the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmldoctype) for the details.