# User agent stylesheet overwriting site styles

Tags: html, css

I am getting the following when I inspect an anchor element (Computed Style)

[image: Computed Style in Chrome Browser]

Most of the posts I have seen on the internet (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308234/user-agent-stylesheet-overriding-my-table-style-twitter-bootstrap)) point to incorrect Doctype. To be sure I validated both my HTML5 and CSS3 codes using w3 validators. But no joy

Can some one please explain me why user agent stylesheet is overwriting the site stylesheets ?

My source code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<footer>
<ul class="foot-link-ul">
    <li class="foot-link-box-li"><a href="/compare-plans">Compare Plans</a></li>
</ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
footer {
    width: 986px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 50px 7px 5px 7px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: there's probably a missing `}` in your CSS or a wrong selector. Impossible to guess without having a look at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors have a higher priority than any of the container elements (divs, spans, etc...), say `.nav` is your container element and you've set the color to gray, the color of anchors would still be the default blueish, since it has a higher priority. To overcome this, you need to define for example `.nav a` or even the sitewide `a` in your `basic.css` file.

EDIT

According to your new edit, you need to define `footer a`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I generally have inherit for anchor elements in my reset. Somehow [HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) seem to miss it

Comment: You're welcome. I usually rely on my own reset rules, especially with small projects where you need to reset only a handful of elements, preferably as you encounter them.

Answer (score 1):

The user agent style sheet targets the `<a>` which would obviously overwrite any inherited style, so you have to target the `<a>` if you want to overwrite the user agent styles.