# Bootstrap inverse table and thead not styling correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, css-tables

While working on a Bootstrap-based project, I came across a strange issue where some of the styling was being overridden by the user agent stylesheet (in Chrome and Firefox). I found [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308234/user-agent-stylesheet-overriding-my-table-style-twitter-bootstrap), which was solved by including the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag I had initially omitted. But now I can't get the `.table-inverse`, `.thead-inverse`, or `.thead-default`classes to shade my table headers. As far as I understand, I have all the necessary rows, containers, etc in place.

Why isn't the shading working?

```css
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2 class="display-1">Bootstrap 4 Inverse Table</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <table class="table table-inverse">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2nrn18a/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add `bootstrap-X.X-flex.css` too.

```
bootstrap-X.X.css
bootstrap-X.X-flex.css
bootstrap.js
```

Where `X.X` is the version number

**OR**

Use this CDNs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That'll do it. Didn't realize this was v4 stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Where do I find bootstrap-X.X-flex.css?

Comment: @embe [Flexbox support has finally come to Bootstrap. Opt-in to the new CSS layout styles with the flick of a variable or the swap of a stylesheet.](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/)

Answer (score 26):

For anyone like me finding this thread but using Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2 or later, **table-inverse** and **thead-inverse** have been replaced with **-dark** per the version release information linked [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.2)

Answer (score 23):

Be sure you are using < th > instead < td > into  header.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I always build tables with only TD and just assumed the style would apply.

Comment: Yes, Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

It happens for the older versions of bootstrap only. Because the class `thead-inverse` is not available there. You can just add this design to your design `css` I hope it will definitely work as I have done so. The reason behind this is  `thead-inverse` is only available in recent versions of `bootstrap.css` only.

```
.thead-inverse th {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #373a3c;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough. The CSS sheet you're linking to in your fiddle doesn't include the `.table-inverse` styling.

Comment: I knew you could pick and choose which bootstrap JS files to download, but I thought that all bootstrap CSS came in one file. Where do I find the additional CSS files for things like the `.table-inverse` styling?